# Get reason for onStop()

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I have an android application where I always send data automatically when moving it to the foreground. An image either chosen from gallery or shot with the camera itself can be part of the data. When chosen by the gallery, my app doesn't go into the background and everything works fine. But when I shoot an image with the camera, the app goes into the background and when it resumes it instantly sends the data without the image because it wasn't processed yet in that time.
So now I want to set a flag whenever the camera is launched and my application is sent to the background because of that, so that I can check like this e.g.

```
@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
public void onMoveToForeground() {
    if (SomeSingleton.getInstance().getFlag() != 1) {
        sendData()
    } else {
        SomeSingleton.getInstance().setFlag = -1;
    }
}
```

But to set that flag I first need to know the reason for the onStop(), to make sure the app didn't get stopped for something else. I want to do something like this then:

```
@Override
public final void onStop() {
    if (cameraInUse()) {
        SomeSingleton.getInstance().setFlag(1);
    }
    super.onStop();
}
```

Is this somehow possible and if yes how?

Comment: Why don't you set the flag when camera is opened rather than when onStop is called?

Comment: @Rohit5k2 well that would be even better, unfortunately I use [this library](https://github.com/jrvansuita/PickImage) and can't access my singleton to set the flag when launching the camera

Comment: You must have the camera opening control in your part of code or you don't?

Comment: No I don't launch the camera in my Code, I just launch the dialog where the user can click on either the camera or gallery icon; and when the picture is either chosen or taken I just handle the result (path of the picture being saved). Launching the camera is being handled in the library. If I could handle that, I would just set the flag as soon as the picture is saved after it being shot by the user.

Comment: onPause is better I think, no?

Comment: This library is open. I would suggest implementing a call back in the dialog. It would give you the option selected on the dialog in your code and you can work on it accordingly.

Comment: @SiloéBezerraBispo yes I think you are right

Comment: See this here. It has the option I am talking about https://github.com/jrvansuita/PickImage#additionals

Comment: @Rohit5k2 bro I love you, this is exactly what I needed. Thank you for taking your time! Can you please post this as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: @foobar: Thanks. Posted my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library you are using has the option to add your own click listeners for camera and gallery (using `IPickClick`).

As per to documentation at https://github.com/jrvansuita/PickImage#additionals you can do something like this

```
PickImageDialog.build(setup)
    .setOnClick(new IPickClick() {
        @Override
        public void onGalleryClick() {
            SomeSingleton.getInstance().setFlag(0); // use your code to set flag for gallery
        }

        @Override
        public void onCameraClick() {
            SomeSingleton.getInstance().setFlag(1); // use your code to set flag for camera
        }
     }).show(this);
```

Now you can use this flag to check if your app went in the background on camera or gallery click.